# Rubocop cant find inherit_gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubocop

Running rubocop from my rails app root with rubocop configured to use the inherit_gem property gives the error;

```
Unable to find gem gem_name; is the gem installed? Gem::MissingSpecError
```

But the gem I confirmed the gem installed with bundler and in the Gemfile.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you run it with `bundle exec rubocop` or just `rubocop`?

Comment: Just `rubocop` I posted an answer that works just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md#inheriting-configuration-from-a-remote-url , the error is because the inherit_gem was installed via bundler. So `rubocop` has to be called with bundler like;

`$ bundle exec rubocop <options...>`